Error: ENOENT: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied), open /data/user/0/com.app/databases/database.db, API 29 android 10
This error happen after i copy a file of my personal path, how documents, downloads, DCIM... to root path of my app, the folder of database of my app, i am using sqlite3.
So i search for solution for long time and nothing that i tried did not work.
but i just change the androidmanifest.xml, and dont work, im using react native then i should change my code?
this is my androidmanifest.xml:
 <manifest>
<uses-permission
android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
android:maxSdkVersion="28"
/>
<uses-permission 
android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" 
android:maxSdkVersion="28"
/>
<uses-permission 
android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" 
android:maxSdkVersion="28"/>
    ...
<application 
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
android:preserveLegacyExternalStorage="true" 
... >
        ...
        <activity> 
            ...
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest> 

and this my code react native to copy to database app path:
  const importDB = useCallback(async () => {
try {
  const response = await DocumentPicker.pick({
    presentationStyle: 'fullScreen',
    copyToCacheDirectory: true,
  });
  setFileResponse(response);
  
  response.map((file, index) => ( 
     ulr_import = file?.uri
  ));


  FileSystem.copyFile(ulr_import, `/data/user/0/com.app/databases/database.db` )
  .then((success) => {
      console.log('file moved!'+success);

        Alert.alert('Confirmation', 'Sucess', [
           {text: 'OK', onPress: () => console.log('OK Pressed')},
         ]);     
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log("Error: " + err.message); // <--- but copyFile returns "doesn't exists" error for temp.jpg
    Alert.alert('Erro', err.message, [
      {text: 'OK', onPress: () => console.log('OK Pressed')},
    ]); 
  });

} catch (err) {
  console.warn(err);
}

}, []);
